# List all functions inside a given function

Tags: r, function, parsing

I would like to map the relations and dependencies of different functions from different scripts.

By now, I´m able to extract all the functions for a given script but I would like to get one level deeper, and try to list all the functions contained in each function.

I´m using the package "NCmisc" and list.functions.in.file function to do the first listing.

```r
rfile <- file.choose() # choose an R script file with functions
list.functions.in.file(rfile) # list all the functions
```

As a result, it returns the list containing all the functions, but I would like to apply a similar procces to parse all functions inside a given function and complete the "mapping" to that level of detail.

Any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible meanings to "all functions inside a given function".

1. If you mean all functions called from a given function, use `codetools::findGlobals(fn, merge = FALSE)$functions`.  This will list everything referenced from within `fn` that wasn't defined there.
2. If you mean all functions defined within a given function, that's a little harder.  I think there are other `codetools` functions that would let you put this together, but I don't know the details.

Comment: Thank you! the meaning was the first you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package [funspotr](https://github.com/brshallo/funspotr) that lists all the functions inside a file. E.g.

```r
funspotr::spot_funs("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brshallo/f0cdfd38f31947b5edbe3efd8efab036/raw/5979cdc0696911eb0fced82f62c289cdc46dbc8d/if_all-if_any-examples.R")
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    funs      pkgs      in_multiple_pkgs
#>    <chr>     <chr>     <lgl>           
#>  1 library   base      FALSE           
#>  2 set.seed  base      FALSE           
#>  3 map       purrr     FALSE           
#>  4 runif     stats     FALSE           
#>  5 set_names purrr     FALSE           
#>  6 paste0    base      FALSE           
#>  7 as_tibble dplyr     TRUE            
#>  8 mutate    dplyr     FALSE           
#>  9 filter    dplyr     TRUE            
#> 10 if_all    dplyr     FALSE           
#> 11 where     (unknown) FALSE           
#> 12 if_any    dplyr     FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>